# Checking the relation between two questions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, categorical-data, agreement-statistics

I have set of answers obtained from different respondents to the following questions (with available answers):

Q1 --> Do you think **this** practice is bad?
A1 --> YES or NO.

Q2 --> What is the severity of **this** practice?
A2 --> 1-5 Likert scale answer.

Q1 and Q2 is repeated for every category and represented with "**this**" in the questions. I have 12 categories. I want to check if the answers of Q1 and Q2 are correlated with each other for every category. Which statistical test can I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this would be T-test treating Q1 as the grouping variable and Q2 as the continuous variable.

In R, you would simply separate each question into two groups (Yes group and No group) and then use:

```
t.test(NoGroupData,YesGroupData)
```

This would perform a statistical test for if each group was different, and give you an estimate of the magnitude of the difference. There are also some nonparametric alternatives if your sample size is low.

Comment: Q2 is not continuous though. Is it a correct approach?

Comment: With Likert scale questions we do sometimes have this problem because while they are ordered, we can't be sure of their spacing. However, it is common to make this assumption when analyzing survey data. A limitation, yes, but generally considered acceptable.

Comment: Hmm I see thank you for the clarification. Is it the same T-test to match Q2 with another question that is alike Q2?

Comment: By the way, I just realized your note at the bottom. Yes, my sample size is low (<30). What is the non parametric alternative?